# Creating a graph for data in python, making a financial calculator

Tags: python

I'm working on a question that's asking me to create a program that calculates an interest rate, but I'm lost as to how I'm supposed to graph this image. I've imported matplotlib but it's not working as expected...Screenshot is below..Any help is appreciated.

Here's the question: How long would it take to pay off $20,000 in student loans with a 4% interest rate if you paid $100 per month? Approximately how much would you have to pay per month to pay off the loan in ten years? (Explain these questions by adding the graph that plotted in your program)

Here's what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

money=6000
flag=0 #Mark the month in each year
for i in range (30,(72-30)*12+1,1):
    if flag==12:
        money+=200
        money*=1.03
        flag=0
    else:
        money+=200
    flag+=1

pyplot.plot(range(money +1))
pyplot.xlabel('money')
pyplot.ylabel('Years remaining')
pyplot.show()
    
        
    
    
print(money)
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework question, and your question is about envisioning a graph, not about coding. Also, please do your research before posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking specifically about your technical problem, you are trying to apply `range` to a float variable (`money` variable becomes a float when you multiply it iteratively by 1.03). So if you want to use `range`, make sure you are using an int type variable.

Secondly, it's good that you know that the `plot` function can receive more than one argument as well. So, if you want, you can specify your `x` and your `y` like this:

```
pyplot.plot(x,y)
```

Now, regarding your question, I'll let you interpret and solve the problem, as @kate-melnykova well observed, it looks like homework.
So good luck!